How to reproduce this equation itemization?

As title states, I'm curious as to how to reproduce this sort of equation itemization. I've managed to reproduce the multiple aligned items after the \equiv through a \begin{centre} ... \end{centre} coupled with \begin{varwidth} ... \end{varwidth} and an enumeration within it framework but the way in which to make it so the \lor all align to the right has hitherto eluded me.
Many thanks in advance to any and all responses.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you try so far. Help us to help you. Where is defined your máx operator ?

@Zarko - I think the easiest way to produce máx is to load babel with spanish as the language option and then write \max in math mode. :-)

@Mico, thank you for explanation. In my native language this is not a case, especial not in math domain. So "max" is not converted to "maks". Foreign words (Latin, English etc) origin we write in original (latin) alfabet regardless that they contains letters not existed in our alphabet ...

Here's a solution that employs an alignat*{2} environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' environment
\usepackage{newtx}   % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
(x_1,y_1) \le_2 (x_2,y_2) \equiv
     \max(x_1,y_1) &< \max(x_2,y_2)                   && \lor \\
    [\max(x_1,y_1) &= \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 < x_2]  && \lor \\
    [\max(x_1,y_1) &= \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 = x_2 \land y_1 \le y_2]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}


It's easy with array.
I locally set the column padding to zero and increase the row spacing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
(x_1,y_1) \le_2 (x_2,y_2) & \equiv &
   \max(x_1,y_1) < \max(x_2,y_2) \hfill \lor \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 < x_2\bigr) \hfill \lor \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 = x_2 \land y_1 \le y_2\bigr)
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


Alternative typesetting:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\unaccentedoperators

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
(x_1,y_1) \le_2 (x_2,y_2) & \equiv &
   \max(x_1,y_1) < \max(x_2,y_2) \hfill \lor \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 < x_2\bigr) \hfill \lor \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 = x_2 \land y_1 \le y_2\bigr)
\end{array}
\]

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
(x_1,y_1) \le_2 (x_2,y_2) & \equiv &
   \max(x_1,y_1) < \max(x_2,y_2) \lor {} \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 < x_2\bigr) \lor {} \\
&& \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 = x_2 \land y_1 \le y_2\bigr)
\end{array}
\]

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
(x_1,y_1) \le_2 (x_2,y_2)
& \equiv & \max(x_1,y_1) < \max(x_2,y_2) \\
& \lor   & \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 < x_2\bigr) \\
& \lor   & \bigl(\max(x_1,y_1) = \max(x_2,y_2) \land x_1 = x_2 \land y_1 \le y_2\bigr)
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


I know that the Spanish tradition is to accent “máx”, but it's actually an abbreviation of a Latin word, not of a Spanish one.

I don't know if that's true! English doesn't have a distinct word for maximum (or minimum) other than the actual Latin word, does it? In Spanish we refer to máximo, mínimo, ínfimo, supremo, etc. and so use máx, mín, ínf, sup, etc. Additionally, even if we considered "maximum" by itself, a Spanish transliteration of the word would still use an accent (i.e. "máximum") just as is used with words like "referéndum".

@Sho It’s true that English borrowed from Latin, but it’s irrelevant, because the notation predates the usage of English as lingua franca.;“max” is a symbol, no longer  an abbreviation.In Italy we use “max” notwithstanding that the word is “massimo”.

You raise a good point there! While it is true as you say that the Spanish tradition seems to have opted for the accentuation with lím, ínf, máx, etc., I do see your point as to why that is ultimately unneccesary given the Latin roots of such terms and their usage as symbols rather than linguistic expressions. I apologize if I seemed dismissive at first!
